# Possible to add script for google slide to make slide background image cover and keep aspect-ratio?

Tags: google-apps-script, background-image, background-size, google-slides

I want to upload background image to a Google Slide and keep the original image aspect-ratio.

As per default, the image automatically stretch across (100% 100%) the area.

(Not to be confused with inserting a regular image).

Is there a solution for this using a script?

Comment: When the aspect ratio of the image is different from that of the slide page, how do you want to do for the part that extends outside the slide page?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].